# Can I connect the LAN of one PoE injector to a LAN port of another PoE injector?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, power-over-ethernet, ubiquiti

I want to transfer Wi-Fi over Ethernet and then convert it to Wi-Fi again. The setup I have right now consists of using two Ubiquiti Nanostation Loco M2 (Loco M2s) one as a station and the other as an Access Point. I am connecting them via their 24V PoE injectors and I am connecting both LAN ports together, [see attached figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dt2z.png). My idea is for the station to read the SSID of the original Wi-Fi and then transmit the data over Ethernet (LAN port to LAN port) inject it over PoE to the Access point to convert it to Wi-Fi.

I am having issues with this system, though. The Loco M2s keep on losing connection and breaking. The Power and LAN LEDs remain ON; however, I can't ping or connect to the M2s anymore. I opened the Loco M2s to look at the circuit (to check if something burned or any obvious circuit issue) but didn't find any. I tried connecting the Loco M2s to a switch to monitor what is going on, but they showed disconnected (on the switch GUI) they showed connected a couple times for a split second, but then show disconnected (with the Power and LAN LEDs ON). I also tried factory resetting them, but that didn't solve the issue either.

Do you know what might be going on? Can connecting the LAN ports together the cause?

Answer (score 1):

That should generally work fine. The 'LAN' ports of the injectors really behave as ordinary Ethernet ports – I've not heard of any PoE injector leaking anything in the wrong direction.

(I *think* they have the usual Ethernet transformer-isolation that should make it impossible? I'm not into electronics. But either way, M series are only 100 Mbps Ethernet devices, so the 'power' pairs are completely separate from the 'data' pairs.)

That being said, these older NanoStations and PicoStations tend to die a lot; I've had more than a few that just stopped working after a few years of use. (Several times it was due to the flash storage breaking down – one AP kept running for almost a year without anyone being able to log in to it.)

Comment: Aha, thanks! Actually, that happened to me, one Loco M2 still worked as an AP, but I couldn't ping it. Mine don't even last a year, they die after a couple of uses (I use this system when needed, it isn't permanently ON) Do you know what might be causing the flash storage to break down? Could it be a power surge from the injector?

Comment: I have no idea, although not lasting even a year is very unusual. (I still really doubt it's from the connection, though – more likely the environment...) After the first few failures, have you tried always using a switch in between? Do they run at maximum power?

Comment: Maybe a power surge occurred, however, I am not totally sold on that because the injector has a surge suppressor in it. No, I haven't tried using the switch, yet. I haven't looked into the airOS while they were ON to answer the power question.